# C# custom control redraw slow

Tags: c#, forms

I have a C# Forms program with about 200 controls total. Some are within user controls which I have added to the Form. When I ran my program on my home machine, a Dual core AMD X64, 2.0Ghz with an ATI X1600 card, the program runs fine. It's fast and redraw is not a problem.

When I put this program onto my desktop, a quad core Intel 2.4Ghz, 4GB RAM, and a NVidia Gefore 8800GT, it slowed to a crawl when redrawing. Could this be a driver issue?

I have Double buffering enabled for all of my user controls and forms. No help there.

I have read this thread, but my situation is not the same:
[Super slow C# custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587856/super-slow-c-custom-control)

Comment: I have to say, the user controls have a faster redraw in design mode than when running. Also, On my AMD machine with the ATI card, the form displays almost instantly while on the NVidia machine the form takes about 10 seconds to draw.

Comment: Have you made sure all the drivers are up to date?

Comment: With those numbers it must be a driver issue. You can confirm with a little app that times the drawing of 100000 lines or something.

Comment: I'm using group boxes a lot. There is probably 30-40 of them on the screen at once and with that, a fairly deep hierarchy of children stemming form the Form.

Comment: Actually, if talking about winforms, the graphics card should have nothing to do with it since GDI+ is not hardware accelerated, isn't it?

Comment: I thought GDI+ was changed to use DirectX. Though, this might be on Vista and Win7 systems. However, this problem is only exhibited on a Win2K3 system with the NVidia card.

Comment: Are you using the same version of the .net framework everywhere?

Comment: Indeed I am. I just upgraded my NVidia driver and it runs a bit faster. Still it's not as fast as my ATI based laptop.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is ".SuspendLayout();" is not really stop drawing. i can't remember the statement but i believe u can get it on google.
and try to using .AddRange might help.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that drawing controls is like painting on a 2D surface, overlapping as required.  If the control does not understand things like rectangle clipping, it could be drawing a portion of the control that is not visible (especially controls that are hidden in another container, like a *TabPage*), wasting valuable CPU cycles.  Additionally, controls that have their *BackColor* as transparent will attempt to mimic transparency by adopting the *BackColor* of its parent control.  Since all of this occurs on GDI+, which is not hardware accelerated, having many controls that exhibit this behavior will exacerbate the slow down.